# Bridge+command pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, command, bridge

I’m reading up on the command pattern and I’m seeing examples from different sites that seem to use bridge+command pattern to showcase the command pattern.

So first, from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern, the definition of the command pattern:

> The command pattern is a behavioral design pattern in which an object
>   is used to encapsulate all information needed to perform an action or
>   trigger an event at a later time. This information includes the method
>   name, the object that owns the method and values for the method
>   parameters.

So with that definition, the command pattern seems pretty straightforward and reading the book located here: https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#commandpatternjavascript, this example does just that.

```
(function(){

  var carManager = {

    // request information
    requestInfo: function( model, id ){
      return "The information for " + model + " with ID " + id + " is foobar";
    },

    // purchase the car
    buyVehicle: function( model, id ){
      return "You have successfully purchased Item " + id + ", a " + model;
    },

    // arrange a viewing
    arrangeViewing: function( model, id ){
      return "You have successfully booked a viewing of " + model + " ( " + id + " ) ";
    }

  };

  carManager.execute = function ( name ) {
    return carManager[name] && carManager[name].apply( carManager, [].slice.call(arguments, 1) );
  };

  console.log(carManager.execute( "arrangeViewing", "Ferrari", "14523" ));
  console.log(carManager.execute( "requestInfo", "Ford Mondeo", "54323" ));
  console.log(carManager.execute( "requestInfo", "Ford Escort", "34232" ));
  console.log(carManager.execute( "buyVehicle", "Ford Escort", "34232" ));

})();
```

There is no extra stuff in this example, I only see the command pattern.  However, back to Wikipedia, they use the following example to showcase the command pattern:

```
class Switch {
  constructor() {
    this._commands = [];
  }

  storeAndExecute(command) {
    this._commands.push(command);
    command.execute();
  }
}

class Light {
  turnOn() { console.log('turn on') }
  turnOff() { console.log('turn off') }
}

class FlipDownCommand {
  constructor(light) {
    this._light = light;
  }

  execute() {
    this._light.turnOff();
  }
}

class FlipUpCommand {
  constructor(light) {
    this._light = light;
  }

  execute() {
    this._light.turnOn();
  }
}

var light = new Light();
var switchUp = new FlipUpCommand(light);
var switchDown = new FlipDownCommand(light);
var s = new Switch();

s.storeAndExecute(switchUp);
s.storeAndExecute(switchDown);
```

When I see this example above, I immediately see the bridge pattern and then see the command pattern because they are storing and then immediately invoking the commands.

My question is this; am I right in thinking the wikipedia example is using bridge+command pattern to showcase the command pattern?

EDIT:

If I take the 2nd example, and remove the command parts, is this not the bridge pattern?

```
class Light {
  turnOn() { console.log('turn on') }
  turnOff() { console.log('turn off') }
}

class FlipDownCommand {
  constructor(light) {
    this._light = light;
  }

  execute() {
    this._light.turnOff();
  }
}

class FlipUpCommand {
  constructor(light) {
    this._light = light;
  }

  execute() {
    this._light.turnOn();
  }
}

var light = new Light();
var switchUp = new FlipUpCommand(light);
var switchDown = new FlipDownCommand(light);

switchUp.execute();
switchDown.execute();
```

Comment: Not sure about the bridge/command stuff, but the JS code that you show as a command example doesn't work. Even if the IIFE made its `carManager` object available outside the IIFE (which it doesn't) it doesn't have an `.execute()` method.

Comment: Sorry, I did not copy the code example correctly.  That has been corrected.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly confuses you about the above examples, and what you would like to know?

Comment: I just edited my question with a third example to help clarify what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, I find the interpretation of Addy Osmani in the js example a bit different from the original interpretation of GoF (and also from the Wikipedia definition).

From GoF Command Pattern page:

> The command pattern is a design pattern that enables all of the information for a request to be contained within a single object. The command can then be invoked as required, often as part of a batch of queued commands with rollback capabilities.

This means, that a command object should contain one parameterless `Execute` method (and sometimes also an `Undo`). The parameters of the command should be 
already contained within it. The command can be passed into an invoker, queued, and executed any time later.
The Wikipedia example is very similar to the original GoF and follows that definition.
It doesn't use the Bridge pattern.

The Bridge pattern is used to add an abstraction level and hide the technical concrete implementation of a service from the consumer.
The bridge can have many operations as defined by its interface.

Comment: Can you please look at my 3rd example I just added.  Would you consider that example the bridge pattern?

Comment: No, it's still the commands pattern, just without the invoker. Where is the service and where is the abstraction? since you are talking about javascript, it's a bit hard to create a good bridge pattern. You should look at examples for Java/C#